# Nested some-function stays on first element

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested

Hi Guys I have the following code:

```
arr = [
  [33, 33],
  [44, 44],
  [55, 55]
]
val = [33, 33]

thereIsCollision = (val, arr) => {
  arr.some((currentVal) => {
    console.log(`check currentVal ${currentVal}`);
    return (Math.abs(currentVal[0] - val[0])) 
     && (Math.abs(currentVal[1] val[1]));

  })
}

thereIsCollision(val, arr);
```

I want to check wether the val is same as values in arr.

However the problem here is when I do the console.log it stays on the [33,33].

Happy to get some help.

Kind regards.

Comment: You're missing `return` statement before `arr.some`. However, it's unclear which `console.log` you meant there, you're not even filtering `arr`.

Comment: Why would you expect it to go further? Your `val` already collides with the first element of the `arr`, so `some` returns `true` immediately after checking the first element.

Comment: I would assume the `some` is returning early

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript `some()` function **immediately returns** as one of the items meet the condition as the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some#Description) state:

> The some() method executes the callback function once for each element present in the array until it finds the one where callback returns a truthy value (a value that becomes true when converted to a Boolean). If such an element is found, some() immediately returns true. Otherwise, some() returns false. callback is invoked only for indexes of the array with assigned values. It is not invoked for indexes which have been deleted or which have never been assigned values.

If none of your elements were to satisfy the condition, it would print all as follows:

```js
const arr = [
  [33, 33],
  [44, 44],
  [55, 55]
]
const val = [33, 33]

const thereIsCollision = (val, arr) => {
  arr.some((currentVal) => {
    console.log(`check currentVal ${currentVal}`);
    return false;
    // return (Math.abs(currentVal[0] - val[0]) < 22) && (Math.abs(currentVal[1] - val[1]) < 22);

  })
}

thereIsCollision(val, arr);
```

Comment: Better keep the original code but demonstrate the behaviour by using a different `val`ue or `arr`ay.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you code execution is

Index 0: return (33 - 33) && (33 - 33) // which is false 
Index 1: return (44 - 33) && (44 - 33) // which is true

At the index 1, Since `some` callback function is returning true, it will not proceed to Index 2. This is the reason, you are seeing only part of console logs.

Other issues in the code

1. missing return return statement for collision function
2. Above check has to be reverse. (when items are equal return true)
3. missing `-` (minus) in return && condition.

Here is with fixes and make use of `every`

```js
arr = [
  [33, 33],
  [44, 44],
  [55, 55]
]


thereIsCollision = (val, arr) => {
  return arr.some((currentVal) => {
    console.log(`check currentVal ${currentVal}`);
    return currentVal.every((cv, i) => cv === val[i]);
  })
}

console.log("[33, 33] Exist?  ", thereIsCollision([33, 33], arr));
console.log("[88, 88] Exist?  ", thereIsCollision([88, 88], arr));
```